# conditions on undefined keys in defaultdict

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict

I am new to python
I wanna write a code using defaultdict in collections module in which , something like this:
defaultdict (lambda:'0') 
but I want the values of only those undefined keys to 0 for which key is greater than 0 like for eg: I have this dict = {'24' : 3 ,'43' : 6} for dict['80'] it should be 0 but for  dict['-5'] it should be 1. Can someone please help

Comment: Why are the keys strings if you care about their numerical values?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `defaultdict`. Instead, subclass `UserDict`

```
from collections import UserDict

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0 if int(key) > 0 else 1

d = MyDict({'24' : 3 ,'43' : 6})
print(d['24'])
print(d['80'])
print(d['-5'])
```

Outputs

```
3
0
1
```